# Facing neutron-dhcp-agent error after installation of neutron-dhcp-agent, How to resolve this?

Tags: openstack, dhcp, openstack-neutron

I tried openstack setup in RHEL 8.3,  installed neutron-dhcp-agent after successful installation status showing as 'active' but I'm getting this following error constantly. I even tried this setup with different VM but result is same.

status, displayed as following,

```
[root@kbshostname ~]# systemctl status neutron-dhcp-agent
● neutron-dhcp-agent.service - OpenStack Neutron DHCP Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/neutron-dhcp-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-04-05 04:47:14 PDT; 1h 10min ago
 Main PID: 117328 (/usr/bin/python)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 49506)
   Memory: 109.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/neutron-dhcp-agent.service
           └─117328 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/neutron-dhcp-agent --config-file /usr/share/neutron/neutron-dist.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/>

Apr 05 05:57:48 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:48.315 158168 ERROR privsep
Apr 05 05:57:48 kbshostname sudo[158173]:  neutron : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.>
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 CRITICAL privsep [-] Unhandled error: PermissionError: [>
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep   File "/bin/privsep-helper", line 10, in >
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep     sys.exit(helper_main())
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/o>
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep     sock.connect(cfg.CONF.privsep_sock_pat>
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission den>
Apr 05 05:57:49 kbshostname neutron-dhcp-agent[117328]: 2021-04-05 05:57:49.935 158176 ERROR privsep
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

Following in observed in log file /var/log/neutron/dhcp-agent.log

```
'--config-file', '/usr/share/neutron/neutron-dist.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/neutron.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini', '--config-dir', '/etc/neutron/conf.d/neutron-dhcp-agent', '--privsep_context', 'neutron.privileged.default', '--privsep_sock_path', '/tmp/tmp72s6q5nm/privsep.sock']
2021-03-30 19:48:12.214 8976 CRITICAL oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep helper command exited non-zero (1)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent [-] Unable to enable dhcp for 25b5a10b-3d49-44d5-8c81-c7ac01201cc3.: oslo_privsep.daemon.FailedToDropPrivileges: privsep helper command exited non-zero (1)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/dhcp/agent.py", line 178, in call_driver
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     getattr(driver, action)(**action_kwargs)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/dhcp.py", line 257, in enable
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     common_utils.wait_until_true(self._enable, timeout=300)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/common/utils.py", line 703, in wait_until_true
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     while not predicate():
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/dhcp.py", line 269, in _enable
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     interface_name = self.device_manager.setup(self.network)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/dhcp.py", line 1672, in setup
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     ip_lib.IPWrapper().ensure_namespace(network.namespace)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 246, in ensure_namespace
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     if not self.netns.exists(name):
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 727, in exists
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     return network_namespace_exists(name)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 935, in network_namespace_exists
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     output = list_network_namespaces(**kwargs)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 921, in list_network_namespaces
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     return privileged.list_netns(**kwargs)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_privsep/priv_context.py", line 246, in _wrap
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     self.start()
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_privsep/priv_context.py", line 258, in start
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     channel = daemon.RootwrapClientChannel(context=self)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_privsep/daemon.py", line 367, in __init__
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent     raise FailedToDropPrivileges(msg)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent oslo_privsep.daemon.FailedToDropPrivileges: privsep helper command exited non-zero (1)
2021-03-30 19:48:12.217 8976 ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent 
2021-03-30 19:48:12.221 8976 INFO neutron.agent.dhcp.agent [-] Finished network 25b5a10b-3d49-44d5-8c81-c7ac01201cc3 dhcp configuration
```

I tried changing '/etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf' file permission to neutron:neutron as mentioned in openstack forum but this didn't helped.

NOTE: This setup is deployed with ansible.

Comment: There is just a little bit missing from the top of your agent log. Can you add the full privsep command to your question? Once you know the full command, you could try running it to see why it error-exits. The cause can be quite surprising, as in a question I [encountered on ask.openstack](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/117996/solved-rocky-linuxbridge-agent-privsep-helper-command-exited-non-zero/).

Comment: @berndbausch log updated...

Comment: Currently, the first line of your log reads `'--config-file', '/usr/share/neutron/neutron-dist.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/neutron.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini', '--config-dir', '/etc/neutron/conf.d/neutron-dhcp-agent', '--privsep_context', 'neutron.privileged.default', '--privsep_sock_path', '/tmp/tmp72s6q5nm/privsep.sock']`. At least one line, perhaps several lines before it are missing. They will show the complete `privsep` command and help you figure out why it failed.

Comment: 2021-04-04 23:41:39.241 2009363 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [-] Running privsep helper: ['sudo', '/usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap', '/etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf', 'privsep-helper', '--config-file', '/usr/share/neutron/neutron-dist.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/neutron.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini', '--config-dir', '/etc/neutron/conf.d/neutron-dhcp-agent', '--privsep_context', 'neutron.privileged.default', '--privsep_sock_path', '/tmp/tmpzdsmuim7/privsep.sock']
2021-04-04 23:41:45.543 2009363 CRITICAL oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep helper command exited non-zero (1)

Comment: @berndbausch I updated log in question itself, but seems like someone has to accepts it .. Previous command is executed by privsep.

Comment: You seem to be logging on to Stackoverflow with two different accounts. If you make your edits as vj_d_weird, they don't require approval.

Comment: You could try running the privsep command from the command line: `sudo /usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf privsep-helper --config-file /usr/share/neutron/neutron-dist.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini --config-dir /etc/neutron/conf.d/neutron-dhcp-agent --privsep_context neutron.privileged.default --privsep_sock_path /tmp/tmpzdsmuim7/privsep.sock`. I fear that the socket doesn't exist anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: yes, /tmp/tmpzdsmuim7/privsep.sock this file is does not exists.